# Copied blockchain and gui still saying syncing for aeons

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I've downloaded the blockchain on one machine with the 0.11.0.0 release and then copied that lmdb directory to another machine. Started the gui wallet and pointed it at the lmdb directory but it still looks like it's syncing completely fresh.

The daemon log says synchronised ok. Why doesn't the gui wallet just connect and go?

Answer (score 2):

There are two synchronizations that happen.  The daemon needs to synchronize the blockchain with the network.  It sounds like you did that, and then you transferred the blockchain to another computer.  The next sync is the wallet syncing with the blockchain, where it scans for transactions that belong to it.

If you didn't specify a starting height, the wallet will scan all blocks to ensure there are no outputs destined for it.  If you were to have specified a starting height - since you knew the address was just created - the wallet would have only started scanning at that height, and therefore been done very quickly.

Comment: Upon setting up a new wallet, you're asked.  The wallet scanning/syncing the blockchain is much faster than the daemon downloading/syncing the blockchain, so it's not a big deal to let it go. But, if you want to specify a height, you'll have to restore the wallet again.  The wallet cache keeps track of which blocks it has scanned.  The only way to tell it to scan from a certain height is from a fresh creation/restoration of the wallet.